# What are the cognitive abilites required for strategy games?

Tags: cognitive-psychology

I assume that the cognitive abilities required for most strategy-centric games are more or less same. It is also observed that they have certain intersection with cognitive abilities required for some other activities such as logical reasoning for problem solving (though this seems to be a matter of debate).

**What precisely are the cognitive abilities required for strategy games?**

(I have no knowledge in psychology; When I said *observed* above, the usage is informal.)

PS: I am not interested in simple logical games, and games that bring in social elements (eg. cooperative games)

Context: This question is related to [this](https://chess.stackexchange.com/a/24921/14678) answer for a chess.com question. As humorously put in [this](https://www.theguardian.com/commentisfree/2018/nov/20/world-chess-championship-women-magnus-carlsen) article (see the quote below), this is a question best put to experts on psychology and neuroscience. So, I post the question here in a general form.

> The chess.com online forums are full of commentators (whom one must assume all work as neuroscientists when they’re not playing chess)